# Got 6 hours for rendering one frame in blender, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: animation, rendering, render, blender

I'm new to blender, after creating an animation, I want to render it. With the help of a large number of guides on the Internet, I think, I got the optimal animation rendering settings, as a result, but  the beginning of the animation rendering I get 6 hours to render only 1 frame.

A computer:
RTX 3050 Ti 4gb
Ryzen 7 5800
16gb RAM

Settings:
[image: 1st slide]
[image: 2st slide]

I realize that the problem is in my settings, but I do not understand where.

Also, for some reason, when rendering 1 picture, the entire background I created change to orange due to technical error:
View in blender:
[image: 3st slide]
After render:
[image: 4st slide]

Thank you a lot for your time, I would really appreciate your help

(Im using Blender 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the render time make sure you head onto `Edit > Preferences > System` in that make sure you have `CUDA` enabled in Cycle render services. And for the change in background, that can be caused by some bug. So, upgrade your Blender to at least 3.8, because that's more stabler the its previous ones. Also make sure you have all the dependcy files(.dll) fixed and your DirectX version is 11.